# Связь Много-ко-много в Kohana (ORM)

Tags: orm, kohana, php

Таблицы:

```
Products
id|name|

Categories
id|name_cat|code

Pr_cats
id|pr_id|cat_id
```

Вот две модели:

```
class Model_Categorie extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = 'categories';
    protected $_primary_key = 'code';
    protected $_db_group = 'default';  
   protected $_has_many = array(
       'products'       => array(
                   'model'          => 'product',
                   'foreign_key'    => 'cat_id',
                   'through'        => 'pr_cats',
                   'far_key'        => 'pr_id',   
                   )
          );
}

class Model_Product extends ORM {
    protected $_table_name = 'products';
    protected $_primary_key = 'id';
    protected $_db_group = 'default';
    protected $_has_many = array(
       'categories'       => array(
                   'model'          => 'categorie',
                   'foreign_key'    => 'pr_id',
                   'through'        => 'pr_cats',
                   'far_key'        => 'cat_id',   
                   )
          );
}
```

Вот запрос в контроллере:

```
$products = ORM::factory('product')
                ->with('categorie')
                ->limit($pagination->items_per_page)
                ->order_by('id')
                ->offset($pagination->offset)
              //Какое здесь написать условие что бы выбрало из таблицы products товары с кодом, равным code в таблице categories?
                ->find_all();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А если вот так:

```
// ...
->where('product.code', '=', 'category.code')
->find_all();
```

Comment: ошибка Unknown column 'product.code'

Comment: а в таблице Product вообще есть поле Code?

Comment: связь идет //имя таблицы(колонка)// products (id) -> pr_cats (pr_id) и categoryes(code) -> pr_cats(cat_id)

Comment: не скажу, что у меня много желания угадывать структуру ваших таблиц и связей между ними, но конструкция в вышеописанной форме дожна работать при условии, что вы исправите пример в соответствии со своими данными

Comment: добавил в вопросе структуру таблиц

Comment: что означает "..из таблицы products товары с кодом"? если кодом товара является ID, то:

    ->where('product.id', '=', 'category.code')

Comment: уже решил вопрос

Comment: выложили бы ответ, вдруг кто-то тоже столкнется с таким вопросом